# android running background service even after killing the application

Tags: android, service, background, intentservice, foreground

What I need?
I need something as `startForeground()` but I dont want to show any icon

What apps similars is?
Whatsapp, facebook etc
you can close their apps but a "service" continue running listening for notifications.

Well in my case I need a service for "Send data" event when app has crashed or has been closed.

Answer (score 2):

@Override onStartCommand:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

to kill it use stopSelf(); , the rest of the service logic is up to you :)

Comment: if the the app which start the service is killed or crashed does it continue working?

Comment: If it crashes no it wont and can't be done, But if you close the app , yes and it will continue running.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by launching your service in a different process. In your `AndroidManifest.xml` add this to your `service` tag:

```
android:process="myNewProcess"
```